# cordova-plugin-inapppurchase error: package com.android.vending.billing does not exist

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

After adding the [cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/) to my project, building web assets for android platform fails:

```
<project_folder>\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\alexdisler\inapppurchases\IabHelper.java:33: error: package com.android.vending.billing does not exist
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
                                  ^
<project_folder>\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\alexdisler\inapppurchases\IabHelper.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    ^
  symbol:   class IInAppBillingService
  location: class IabHelper
<project_folder>\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\alexdisler\inapppurchases\IabHelper.java:230: error: package IInAppBillingService does not exist

                mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                                               ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 FAILED
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 12):

Execute this in the root folder of your project (it copies the `aidl` file to the proper folder)

```
ionic cordova platform add android
mkdir platforms\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\
copy platforms\android\src\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl platforms\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\
```

Many thanks to [azarus](https://github.com/azarus) for the [solution](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/issues/196#issuecomment-354012331)

Answer (score 9):

For Mac

```
mkdir -p platforms/android/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing
cp platforms/android/src/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl platforms/android/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Thanks :)

ionic cordova platform add android

mkdir platforms\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\

copy platforms\android\src\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl platforms\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\